# jQuery Chosen not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to fancy up a select form field using the jQuery chosen() plugin, but it's not working.  Here is my HTML code:

```
<label for='aaaaa'>First option or "Second option":</label>
<select name='aaaaa' class="chosen" id='aaaaa'>
<option>First option</option>
<option>"Second option"</option>
</select><br>
```

Here is my .js code:

```
$('.chosen').chosen();
```

Here are my JavaScript imports:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/harvesthq/chosen/master/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jQuery.layout/jquery.layout.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/control_panel/controlpanel.js"></script>
```

Here are my CSS imports:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../css/jQueryui/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/site.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.github.com/harvesthq/chosen/master/chosen/chosen.css" type="text/css" media="Screen" />
<link rel="icon" href="../../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I don't have a picture of how it displays on the screen, but I can describe it. There are five lines:

1. First option or "Second option"
2. First option (in blue and underlined, looks like an html link)
3. (Looks like a text input field)
4. First option (plain text, with a bullet point in front like a

   element

   "Second option" (again plain text, with a bullet point in front like a

   element)

Running in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Could I suggest mocking up a basic ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), or similar (so that we can *see* what's happening)?

Comment: the <script> line importing chosen.jquery.js has a typo

Comment: Is your Javascript call to chosen() located somewhere that ensures the DOM is fully loaded?

Answer (score 2):

I think the class defined in select is wrong.

It should be: `chzn-select`

So your code should be:

```
<select name='aaaaa' class="chzn-select" id='aaaaa'>
```

Comment: With the release of Chosen 1.0, all CSS class names were renamed from a chzn- root to a chosen- root, so chosen-select is correct.

Answer (score 0):

try using firebug console to see if there are any errors regarding js or css files.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when changed firefox user agent to iPhone's user agent. In this case chosen not rendered and the browser will show default select.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am replying very late but your choosen script tag has not been closed properly and the class for select should be  as per your jquery code

Comment: This question is very old. There is a comment already saying that "the <script> line importing chosen.jquery.js has a typo". If you want to point this out, please be more specific and copy the lines that are wrong and write what is wrong in that line. I didn't understand the problem with the "class for select" you mentioned. What is the problem specifically?